# keycloak on kubernetes: x509 auth with ingress

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Does anyone have an example config for x509 authentication w/ Keycloak on Kubernetes via an ingress endpoint? I have x509 working fine w/ a NodePort setup, but access via ingress fails and Keycloak cycles to the username/password form.

```
18:37:54,474 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationProcessor] (default task-2) AUTHENTICATE
18:37:54,474 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationProcessor] (default task-2) AUTHENTICATE ONLY
18:37:54,474 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow] (default task-2) processFlow: x509-browser
18:37:54,475 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow] (default task-2) check execution: 'auth-cookie', requirement: 'ALTERNATIVE'
18:37:54,475 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow] (default task-2) authenticator: auth-cookie
18:37:54,475 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationSelectionResolver] (default task-2) Going through the flow 'x509-browser' for adding executions
18:37:54,475 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationSelectionResolver] (default task-2) Going through the flow 'x509-browser forms' for adding executions
18:37:54,475 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationSelectionResolver] (default task-2) Selections when trying execution 'auth-cookie' : [ authSelection - auth-cookie,  authSelection - auth-x509-client-username-form,  authSelection - auth-username-password-form]
18:37:54,475 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow] (default task-2) invoke authenticator.authenticate: auth-cookie
18:37:54,475 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services.util.CookieHelper] (default task-2) Could not find cookie KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY, trying KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY_LEGACY
18:37:54,475 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services.managers.AuthenticationManager] (default task-2) Could not find cookie: KEYCLOAK_IDENTITY
18:37:54,476 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow] (default task-2) authenticator ATTEMPTED: auth-cookie
18:37:54,476 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow] (default task-2) check execution: 'auth-x509-client-username-form', requirement: 'ALTERNATIVE'
18:37:54,476 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow] (default task-2) authenticator: auth-x509-client-username-form
18:37:54,476 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationSelectionResolver] (default task-2) Going through the flow 'x509-browser' for adding executions
18:37:54,476 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationSelectionResolver] (default task-2) Going through the flow 'x509-browser forms' for adding executions
18:37:54,476 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.AuthenticationSelectionResolver] (default task-2) Selections when trying execution 'auth-x509-client-username-form' : [ authSelection - auth-x509-client-username-form,  authSelection - auth-username-password-form]
18:37:54,476 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow] (default task-2) invoke authenticator.authenticate: auth-x509-client-username-form
18:37:54,476 DEBUG [org.keycloak.services] (default task-2) [X509ClientCertificateAuthenticator:authenticate] x509 client certificate is not available for mutual SSL.
18:37:54,476 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow] (default task-2) authenticator ATTEMPTED: auth-x509-client-username-form
18:37:54,476 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow] (default task-2) check execution: 'x509-browser forms flow', requirement: 'ALTERNATIVE'
18:37:54,476 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow] (default task-2) processFlow: x509-browser forms
18:37:54,476 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow] (default task-2) check execution: 'auth-username-password-form', requirement: 'REQUIRED'
18:37:54,476 DEBUG [org.keycloak.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationFlow] (default task-2) authenticator: auth-username-password-form
```

Comment: What ingress implementation are you using?

Comment: hey @Thomas thansk for the follow-up! nginx ingress

Answer (score 0):

Ingress is just an API and implemented by various providers, which support additional configuration in a product specific way.
In your example it is nginx.

Make sure that nginx is deployed with support for SNI based TLS passthrough, therefore keycloak will receive the original TLS connection and leverage client certificates.

For nginx the ingress configuration for that is an additional annotation:

```
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
```

Relevant documentation: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/#ssl-passthrough

Comment: Ah, yeah, already did that, but absolutely, that needs to be there at a minimum

Comment: So did it work out for you and the question is answered?

Comment: no, still not working, unfortunately

Comment: please share your details incl. how you test it